# A Direct Proof that a Topological Space with Ininitely Many Components is Disconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

It's straightforward to prove that for a topological space, **connected $\iff $ having one component**.
It then follows by contra-positive that **disconnected $\iff$ having more than one component.**

In the case of a finite number of components of a space $\{C_i\}_{i = 1, n}$ a direct proof $X$ is disconnected is that $X$ = $C_1 \cup (\cup _{i = 2, n} C_i)$. Then with each component being closed, the finite union $\cup _{i = 2, n} C_i$ is a closed set and $X$ is the union of two non-empty disjoint closed sets $C_1$, and $ \cup _{i = 2, n} C_i$, which is a standard definition that $X$ is disconnected (and by the way also shows in the finite case that each component is both closed and open).

For the infinite case, the infinite union is not necessarily closed and this argument fails - **is there a direct proof for the infinite case ?**

---

Later clarification after many comments....

In other words, as per one of the comment below, given an infinite number of components can one construct a separation (disconnection) as one can in the finite case ?

Comment: I don't see how you can discuss the number of components being greater than 1 without already knowing it is disconnected.  If you assume you have infinitely many components, it is already disconnected.

Comment: @Randall. You know it's disconnected by the contra-positive. I'm interested if there is a direct proof that relates infinite components to the definition of disconnected being the union of two disjoint sets, both being either open or closed in the same way that I can set (have) set out a proof for the finite case.

Comment: A Space that is a union of infinitely many pairwise disjoint closed sets is not necessarily disconnected. Take for example $[0, 1]$, which is the union over all sets $\{x\}$, where $x \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: I don't understand then.  You already know that proving one component iff connected is easy.  What could be more direct?

Comment: @Dominik True, but $\{x\}$ are not components in $[0, 1]$. Components are maximally connected subsets.

Comment: I understand what you want now, but I don't understand *why* you want it.

Comment: @Randall. Like the mountain - because it's there. Actually I'm just trying to find a confirmatory analysis that shows how the infinite case can be related to the direct definition of disconnected. I see the believers in the open set approach have given up and deleted their answers - pity really, that was a useful insight in itself

Comment: @TomCollinge I didn't understand your question at first. Since my answer did not answer your question, I deleted it.

Comment: @Klaus. Thanks for trying - there is still chance for you to give an applicable answer.

Comment: Would the fact that "maximal connected component" is equivalent to "equivalence class of the relation $x\sim y$ iff every clopen set containing $x$ also contains $y$" be an answer - it at least makes it clear that the definition truly are related... but it doesn't "construct" the clopen set separating a given $x$ and $y$ not in the same component (and I'm not convinced you can? You might be able to do something more constructive with compact Hausdorff spaces, but I'm not sure)

Comment: Your concept of a "direct proof" is unclear to me. For example, I would not call your proof of the finite case a "direct proof" because it uses a theorem about components, namely that each component of $X$ is a closed subset of $X$. To me it's more direct to simply apply the definition of component: if there exists a component $C \subset X$ such that $C \ne X$ then $X$ is not connected, because by definition of component the subset $C$ is a maximal connected subset.

Comment: @LeeMosher I was thinking of a constructive proof similar to the finite case, but your answer also works for my intention in both finite and infinite cases, i.e. show more than one component implies disconnected without simply taking the contra-positive of connected.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thanks: I'm not familiar with that definition - I'll have to think about it.

Comment: There are certainly interesting constructive issues: the existence of a component containing each point; the fact that the set of components is pairwise disjoint and hence partitions the space; and others. But once you admit the definition of a component, then the existence of a component which is a proper subset immediately implies $X$ is disconnected.

Comment: If I've understood you directly, I think there's a perfectly reasonable question here, which is phrased a bit differently than you gave it: given that I know the infinitely many components of a space, can I explicitly construct a disconnection?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes, I hadn't completely thought through what I was looking for when I asked, but that's it. I'm beginning to suspect that the answer is no.

Comment: @TomCollinge Suppose $X$ is the space of rational numbers. The components are the singleton sets. Good luck in "constructing" a separation from that.

Answer (score 1):

A "direct proof" is clear: if $X$ is connected it has one unique component (where a component is **defined** as a maximal connected subset: $C$ is a component of $X$ when $C$ is non-empty, connected and $C \subsetneq C' \subseteq X$ implies $C'$ is *not* connected, or equivalently: $C \subseteq C'\subseteq X$ and $C'$ connected implies $C'=C$).
Because when $X$ is connected then $C=X$ fulfills the definition I gave trivially, and no proper subset can be a component as witnessed by $C'=X$ as well.

So if $X$ has more than one component (the number is irrelevant) we already know $X$ is not connected, as you say by contrapositive.

The other argument you gave for finitely many components is irrelevant and not needed anyway, so the infinite case is a "fake problem". The first paragraph is all you need. A contrapositive implication is no problem.

Comment: All true and thanks for the answer. I now have a better understanding of what I meant in my question, as in the comment from @KevinCarlson saying can you in fact construct a disconnection given an infinite number of components ?